# Access device SDK written in C++ from node JS

Tags: c++, node.js, dll, electron

The below is also with reference to [Accessing an SDK that is written in c++ using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653502/accessing-an-sdk-that-is-written-in-c-using-node-js)

We have a [device](https://www.desko.de/en/products/travel/boarding/penta-bgr.php) that can scan document/barcode/QRcode and give output via USB.  The device manufacturer have given one SDK that is written only in csharp, c++, java.  Now we have decided to go for, accessing c++ code from node.  After a multiple hours of pain I was able to run this c++ code and it was happened to be a console application which will print the scanned document data in console and saves scanned document in a particular location.  Now the requirement is, whatever the device do with the c++ code we need to do it from node as well except printing it in console instead we have to display it in our Web App developed using Angular.  There are few solution I found in internet like,  NAPI and c++ Addon by Node, SWIG for creating wrapper class.  I'm bit confused here on how to proceed because I have no idea on how both the above suggested ways will work or is even feasible for the mentioned requirement.  And also I want make use of the SDK provided by the device manufacturer as it holds all/most of the features of the device.

To sum up the above lengthy requirement:

- I have a c++ SDK that communicate with the device and I want make use
  of this c++ code to access from the node.js,  how can I proceed? If
  I'm going with the any of the above mentioned way, do I need to
  rewrite the c++ code to access from node.js
- [c++ SDK provided by the device manufacturer](https://github.com/cvinodhkumar77/Sample.git), if you want to have
  a look.  It has c++, csharp, java but we can concentrate on c++

All the code in the above mentioned link is subject to copyrights by device manufacturer.  I do not hold any claim on that

Answer (score 1):

For C++ interfaces you would create a C++ addon for node. The addon would expose functions to node as a module e.g `const myCppApi = require('bindings)('yourNativeAddonName')` the difference is that the code behind the module is not javascript but a native wrapper that makes calls to compiled code. Or in other words where you can use the C++ API of your bar scanner.

Examples of this can be found in the node.js API Docs https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

For your purpose, I would recommend using the N-API and neglect the other methods, because the N-API does not rely on you knowing too much about v8 (`v8::` namespace, Isolates, Contexts etc.) and how chromium works. Instead, everything is simplified.

You can check out this example repository for how to work with the N-API
https://github.com/nodejs/abi-stable-node-addon-examples/tree/master/1_hello_world/napi

Helpful hint:
Since I saw you are using electron, make sure to build your module against the same node version as your electron is using. You can check them either by printing `process.version` in the main process or by loocking them up on the electron page.